# Can I "fix" clothes?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Can I use **fix** for talking about clothes?
For example :

> My mother **fixed** the hole in my jeans.

Or is there a better verb I should use?

Comment: I normally use `mended` for clothes.

Comment: I only use *mend* if it involves a needle and thread.  You might *fix* the hole in your jeans with an iron-on patch. I think *fix* is fine for everyday conversation.  Even in everyday conversation I'd probably say, "My mom sewed up the hole in my jeans" rather than *mended* if needle and thread were involved.

Comment: Does the verb mend imply how we are doing it? I know the verb darn indirectly imply thread and needle because darning is to repair by means of stitches interwoven with one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although **fix** is entirely valid, a native speaker would probably use the verb **mend** when talking about clothes:

> I've mended the hole in my socks.
>
> I'm mending this tear in my jacket.
>
> I need to mend my shirt before tomorrow.

Comment: I think you're right.  For me, *mend* is a general word for repairing (e.g.) clothes, and it's not specific to needle and thread as it is for @Jim.  [Dictionaries](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/mend) seem to agree with you, too.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in previous answer, phrases *fix clothes , repair clothes*, and *mend clothes* are used. ([1](http://diyfashion.about.com/od/mendingandalterations/tp/Repair_and_Mend_Clothing.htm), [2](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-Clothes), [3](http://www.hgtv.com/homekeeping/cost-calculation-mending-clothes/index.html), [4](http://tlc.howstuffworks.com/home/how-to-mend-clothes4.htm), [5](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/5-tips-to-mend-damaged-clothing.html)).  Another common term is *to [patch](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Patch-Your-Clothes/)*, meaning to apply a piece of cloth as a [patch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patch#Noun) (sense 1).  *[Reweaving](http://www.thefrenchreweavers.com/faq.htm)* or *[invisible mending](http://www.invisible-mending.co.uk/)* are more-subtle fixes.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but I don't think it's commonly used that way. It's better to use a verb specific to the activity, such as *mend, patch, sew, alter,* etc.
Also you are better communicating what actually occurred rather than generalizing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! You can [fix your clothes](https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&q=he+fixed+the+clothes&spell=1&sa=X&ei=Dck4Uc7eDIim4ASF74DgCw&ved=0CCoQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.Yms&fp=d1e53b8aefa2f39a&biw=1280&bih=822) or *repair* them or *mend* them and can find out it by googling. About a better verb I doubt because people use all three.